# Reliably get labels for Elastic Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, elasticui

I am trying to create a pie chart with elastic charts, and I'm having trouble trying to label the slices.

I'm following the [example](https://elastic.github.io/elastic-charts/?path=/story/sunburst--most-basic&globals=toggles.showHeader:true;toggles.showChartTitle:false;toggles.showChartDescription:false;background:white;theme:light) here. More specifically, for the layers prop:

```
layers={[
          {
            groupByRollup: (d: Datum) => d.sitc1,
            nodeLabel: (d: Datum) => productLookup[d].name,
          },
        ]}
```

The `d` in `groupByRollup` gives me the full entry for the data, but the `d` in `nodeLabel` only gives me the count for the data. There's no example for the `productLookup` object in the storybook.

I assume, oddly, I need to go back to my data object and find the label with the corresponding count. But what if I have a dataset where 2 entries have the same count? How do I reliably get the label?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts/issues/2172

Asked a question in the repo and got it figured out.